# How to script sftp using PSFTP.exe with private and public key

Tags: scripting

We are doing ftp to remote server, and using password, but now they want us to use private and public key instead.
just wonder if any one have done scripting(command line) ftp that use private and public key for authentication this process will be auto run every night.

How would i reference to the private key?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about database administration. Consider [su] instead.

Comment: hahahaha sorry for the mistake, if you do not have answer please do not reply

Comment: Your question is going to be closed - and your rudeness won't make you any friends here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you are using [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) on Windows for this question and if so their documentation is located at [http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp). In their [FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-options), it states:

> **A.6.7 How do I use all PuTTY's features (public keys, proxying, cipher selection, etc.) in PSCP, PSFTP and Plink?**
>
> Most major features (e.g., public keys, port forwarding) are available through command line options. See the documentation.
>
> Not all features are accessible from the command line yet, although we'd like to fix this. In the meantime, you can use most of PuTTY's features if you create a PuTTY saved session, and then use the name of the saved session on the command line in place of a hostname. This works for PSCP, PSFTP and Plink (but don't expect port forwarding in the file transfer applications!).

The documentation states:

> PSFTP accepts all the general command line options supported by the
> PuTTY tools, except the ones which make no sense in a file transfer
> utility.

They have a [section](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-general-opts) that talks about command line options and one of them states:

> The -i option allows you to specify the name of a private key file in
> *.PPK format which PuTTY will use to authenticate with the server.

As an alternative, when I have had to do this with SSIS (since it only supports FTP natively) I typically use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and their scripting documentation is located at http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting. They also have a [simple guide](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) which may be easier to digest if you decide to use that tool.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will do more research and will let you know if i success